couldn't take build after updated unity version from 2021.3.2f1to 2022.3.25f1
I updated the Unity version from 2021.3.2f1 to 2022.3.25f1. now I can't take build. the bug is showing like this: before I updated to this version I didn't have any issues. I just updated because in the 2021.3.2f1. have an audio bug. and that worked on my other projects also. please identify the issue
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-7COAG5S
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-7COAG5S
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-7COAG5S
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = yyzPzalJDwrQcYNuOZam0bhKb26WyyhK
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
SESSIONNAME = Console
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = Ph-837Q6GNodAkyc2MRkxVPUcjlIET4d
NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
windir = C:\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
OS = Windows_NT
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 25 Model 80 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
HOMEPATH = \Users\My
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
OneDriveCommercial = C:\Users\My\OneDrive - Amrita university
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_9136_GEWFOQZWSTPTZKRN
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 25
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.25f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-7COAG5S
TEMP = C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Temp
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
HOMEDRIVE = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
USERNAME = My
OneDrive = C:\Users\My\OneDrive - Amrita university
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = QqyoFpcWPi7V17p80_46CF6-sNGRGbHo
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 16
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 5000
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
TMP = C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Temp
SystemDrive = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
APPDATA = C:\Users\My\AppData\Roaming
Path = C:\Python312\Scripts\;C:\Python312\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\My\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin;C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\My\AppData\Local
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\My
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\My\FireOnTap\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Cannot parse project property android.enableR8='' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at<7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) <7564edb1c71b4762a209de01409ad6c0>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I am using the same version for another project also but those are fine. Only difference is form both projects are this project I am using unity ads.is that could be the issue ?

it is expected, not just possible but expected that if you jump major versions somethings got to change..

i got the solution but the file name is gradleTemplate.properties.

Ahh yes, I ran into a wall with this for like a week or two.
You'll have to go into your maintemplate.gradle / gradletemplate files, and find the EnableR8 line, and remove it. I don't believe R8 is used anymore.
A good way to solve Gradle issues without getting a headache is to skip down to the 'What went wrong' section, take that; and throw it into google -- in this case, it's a very common issue.

i got the solution but the file name is gradleTemplate.properties
